# PHP Ajax jQuery cross domain file loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ace-editor

So before you say this can't be done. These are all files that I have one server. I just have some of them listed under different domains.

My PHP script will access all the files but when I try to do an ajax request to try to load the file I will often get an error (because the site i am accessing is secure and the one I am accessing it through isn't).
What I need is a way to have php grab the file. But I need aJax to retrieve the file and render it for me. I am also using ACE editor to edit the file

The bit of code I have here will actually error out as well because it will load and print out the file where $page is defined but won't load where `htmlspecialchars` is.

```
<script>
var e = ace.edit("editor");
<?php 
    $page = readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_GET['dir']);
    echo 'e.setValue('.htmlspecialchars($page, ENT_QUOTES).');';
 ?>

</script>
```

I have an ajax get request working but it doesn't work when I go to a directory with a special htaccess file. Now I can't change the htaccess file (unless there is a way for me to confirm that it is my script running and not someone else.

`The question is`, how can I access those other files without getting that error? Mind you those files could be extension. It is not limited to just scripts or css, mostly they will be html or php files.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of searching the deep dark depths of the php.net site I was able to put together a solution that works.

```
<?php 
echo htmlspecialchars(
 addslashes(
   file_get_contents(
     $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_GET['d‌​ir']
   ) 
  )
); ?>
```

the `addslashes` is the extra part that I needed. Then I also had to put it between the div for the editor. I couldn't use the `editor.setValue()` function.